# Mirror reflections

Tags: light, mirror

[image]

The problem is i can't find a way to make mirror reflections look good, there are always some kind of distortions that makes render looks odd. Is there any way to improve this? (Sorry for my English)

Comment: this may sound stupid, but you may be using blender render. make sure you are using cycles render, and if not then you may want to make the mirror render a picture to simulate a mirror.

Comment: It looks like there is either something wrong with the normals of the mirrors or a problem with the material you have assigned to the mirrors - I'm assuming it isn't just a straight 'Glossy' shader...? Could you check that your normals are pointing in the correct direction and also share details of your material setup for the mirror (and confirm that this is Cycles rather than Blender Internal render engine).

Answer (score 1):

ok that was stupid. I used smooth shading for my mirror object. Problem solved